# how to preventDefault jquery when click on search

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to close when click everywhere and not close when click on class form-cauta ?

```js
    $("body").on("click",function(){
        $("#searchresult").css("display","none");
    });
    $(".form-cauta , #search , #cauta").on("click",function(){
        $("#searchresult").css("display","block");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-cauta" action="{{URL("search")}}">
    <input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Cauta" autocomplete="off"/>
    <button type="submit" id="cauta">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    </button>
</form> This is body
<div class='searchresult' id="searchresult">
    <ul class='listitemsresult' id='itemssearch'>
    <li>dsasdasdasad</li>
    <li>dsasdasdasad</li>
    <li>dsasdasdasad</li>
    <li>dsasdasdasad</li>
    <li>dsasdasdasad</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How to close when click everywhere and not close when click on class form-cauta ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the **event** as a parameter for the closure function of form click event.

```
$(".form-cauta, #search, #cauta").on("click", function(event){
    event.stopPropagation(); // Passing the event and stoping propagation
    $("#searchresult").css("display", "block");
});
```

### [JsBin Example](http://jsbin.com/hoyanik/5/edit?js,output)

Comment: @ValenTin Not a problem :) Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

Check this working code.

```js
$().ready(function(){
        $("body").on("click",function(){
            $("#searchresult").css("display","none");
        });
        $(".form-cauta , #search , #cauta").on("click",function(){
            $("#searchresult").css("display","block");
        });

         $(".form-cauta").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
<form class="form-cauta" action="{{URL("search")}}">
    <input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Cauta" autocomplete="off"/>
    <button type="submit" id="cauta">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    </button>
</form> This is body
<div class='searchresult' id="searchresult">
    <ul class='listitemsresult' id='itemssearch'>
    <li>dsasdasdasad</li>
    <li>dsasdasdasad</li>
    <li>dsasdasdasad</li>
    <li>dsasdasdasad</li>
    <li>dsasdasdasad</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```